Not able to insert excel values into MS SQL DB
I want to build a dynamic select query for an insert statement.
I have the below table created in MS SQL with 200 columns. If the input Excel file has 10 columns then insertion will start column1 to column10. If I have 20 columns in Excel then data insertion will start from column1 to column20.
All fields names in Excel will go into the dbo.headers table along with filename and the Excel data will go into the dbo.data table along with the filename.
create table dbo.headers (filename varchar(10), column1 varchar(10), column2 varchar(10), column3 varchar(10)....column200 varchar(10)
create table dbo.data (filename varchar(10), column1 varchar(10), column2 varchar(10), column3 varchar(10)....column200 varchar(10)

excelfile = "c:\test.xlsx"
#established connection string to MS SQL DB
data = pd.read_excel(excelfile, sheet_name="sheet1")

table_header_cols = ','.join([f'column{i=1} for i in range(len(data.columns))])
header_cols = ','.join(data.columns)

insert_query = f"insert into dbo.headers({table_header_cols)} 
# I want code from here


I have also tried the following, but it is not inserting values to the data table where it is having headers columns.
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


server = 'DESKTOP-VFQ45HB\\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'test'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={driver}'

def insert_excel_data_to_sql(filename, sheet_name, connection_string):
    # Read Excel file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # Get column names from the DataFrame
    column_names = list(df.columns)

    # Create SQL Alchemy engine
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)

    # Insert column names into headers table
    df_columns = pd.DataFrame(
        {'filename': [filename], **{f'column{i + 1}': [col] for i, col in enumerate(column_names)}})
    df_columns.to_sql('headers', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    df_data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'filename': [filename], **{f'column{i + 1}': [col] for i, col in enumerate(column_names)}})
    df_data.to_sql('data1', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    # Insert data into data table
    # df['filename'] = filename
    # print(df)
    # #df.to_sql('data2', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    # df.to_sql('data1', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, column_names=column_names )
# Example usage
filename = 'C:/Users/PC/Documents/test.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
insert_excel_data_to_sql(filename, sheet_name, connection_string)




The title should provide a specific, technical summary of your question, not a statement of your feelings or a generic title like "programming help". Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask.

The attempts to "fix" the "problem" actually cause it. Nothing special is needed to read an Excel sheet as a DataFrame, or write that DataFrame to a database. insertion will start column1 to column10. not really. Those are the series names created by Pandas because the Excel data had no header. Otherwise read_excel would have used them. You can rename the columns with DataFrame.rename. to_sql will work just fine as long as the series and column names match. No string manipulations are needed

As for I have the below table created in MS SQL with 200 columns. why? That opaque table with generic ultrashort types and meaningless column names is useless for any kind of import or data manipulation. Excel files have a lot of numeric data, stored as binary values. It also has dates, also stored as binary values. Storing them as text leads to conversion errors due to unexpected formatting and make the data completely untrustworthy. Never mind that you won't have any idea what those columns hold due to the meaningless names. Not only is the data mangled now, you can't even query it

All fields names in Excel will go into the dbo.headers table along with filename why? This is an even worse design. This is a critical bug. Tables aren't spreadsheets, they're the actual Relation in RDBMS. A table defines the relation between its fields. Without actual fields, you no longer have a relation or even a table. The data in that table is essentially lost

The reason, we have 1000 excel files and excel file has different fields. I want to import excel field names into header table excel data into data table. Once, i have this, using SQL, am marrying both header.column1 with data.column1

Finally, I cracket it
df.to_sql('data', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, column_names=column_names )
In this, data table, I want to insert filename as a 1st field and field names are same as header columns.
